# LaTeX, Sweave: How to get \upshape (or \rm) in lines which display code?

Tags: sweave

How can get an upshape font (\rm) [with Sweave] in lines which display code (such as `1:300 + runif(300)`) below? I tried a couple of things (I found `fontshape=n` online), but they did not influence the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

% \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small, fontshape=n}
% \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small, fontshape=n}
% \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small, fontshape=n}
\fvset{listparameters={\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}, fontsize=\small}

\SweaveOpts{engine=R, pdf=TRUE, eps=FALSE, width=5.33, height=3}
\SweaveOpts{strip.white=TRUE, keep.source=TRUE}

\begin{document}
<<label=preliminaries, echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
options(width=70, useFancyQuotes="UTF-8", prompt="> ", continue="  ")
options(SweaveHooks=list(fig=function() par(mar=c(4, 4, 0.4, 0.7))))
@
<<label=foo>>=
1:300 + runif(300)
@
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just realized I forgot to load `Sweave`, so this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small, fontshape=n}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small, fontshape=n}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small, fontshape=n}
\fvset{listparameters={\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}}

\SweaveOpts{engine=R, pdf=TRUE, eps=FALSE, width=5.33, height=3}
\SweaveOpts{strip.white=TRUE, keep.source=TRUE}

\begin{document}
<<label=preliminaries, echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
options(width=74, useFancyQuotes="UTF-8", prompt="> ", continue="  ")
options(SweaveHooks=list(fig=function() par(mar=c(4, 4, 0.4, 0.7))))
@
<<label=foo>>=
round(1:300 + runif(300))
@
\end{document}
```